# Is Microsoft Graph API down?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, bad-gateway

I don't know the proper channel to report or ask a question - but is MS Graph API down right at the moment? Maybe due to [recent Cloudflare issues](https://www.cloudflarestatus.com/incidents/xvs51y9qs9dj)?

I'm getting 502 Bad Gateway response both from [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and from my own code.

EDIT:
Issue got resolved around 4-5 hours into the incident, probably due to restarting the infrastructure/services by MS - judging from the HTTP responses during that time.

Comment: It's also down for me. I get "Couldn't retrieve calendar from O365. Message: Code: UnknownError". This on all our environments, since 08:00UTC

Comment: @JFlex Now I'm getting the 503 - I'm guessing they are restarting the infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the inconvenience , There is a health bulletin released by Microsoft for the affected tenants, Users may encounter delays and experience failures when accessing some M365 services includes Microsoft Graph API .

Thanks

Comment: Where I can find this Health Bulletin? Is it send via email to the IT departments? I know there is a Health Check services for O365 that shows information related to the current tenant, but I didn't see the MS Graph API notices.

Comment: https://admin.microsoft.com/#/servicehealth/history/:/alerts/MO394389

Comment: @JFlex yeah, that's exactly what that was about. Thanks!